# IBM Quantum: 20 minutes for 1 shot, timeout for 2 shots. Why?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

It takes 20 minutes for the *ibmq_qasm_simulator* to execute 1 shot of my circuit. Successful always.

It always times out for 2 shots of the same circuit on the same simulator.

One may assume the performance would be roughly linear, say, 40 minutes for 2 shots. No, that has never happened to me. For those who don't know the simulator, its default timeout is supposed to be 166 minutes (10,000 seconds).

Is there a bug somewhere in the simulator?

Comment: Could you please post how does your circuit look like?

Comment: As Martin pointed out, it  would be better if you can specify your circuit in more details. Number of qubits involved, circuit depth, etc

Comment: @MartinVesely I don't think the circuit info would be useful to resolve the issue. Since you've asked for it, here it goes. It uses 25 qubits. The number of the gates and depth are in millions. I am amazed by the ability of the simulator to complete 1 shot in just 20 minutes. The key question is why it times out with 2 shots.